# Project nuget references cant update after moving folder

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Ive moved some code to a new folder within a solution and now ive got nuget all confused about where the packages are.  I tried to edit the .csproj file to point to where the packages are, but I still get complaints.

when running update-package -reinstall i get prompted to save the project files.

I replaced `..\packages\` with `..\..\packages\` to reflect the path to where the packages are, but this doesnt seem to help.

I see this in my csproj file

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.37\build\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.37\build\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.20.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.20.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.20.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.20.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.40\build\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.40\build\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.21.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.21.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.21.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.21.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.20.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.20.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.20.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.20.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.40\build\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.40\build\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.21.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.21.0\build\Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.21.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.0.21.0\build\Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver.Win64.targets')" />
```

[ **update 8/15/2018** ]
This is resolved, I had one reference that was causing the issues and there was an extra "." in there somewhere as in "...\", just had to spot it

Comment: Please fix the tag. This is not `tsql` question

Comment: Since you have resolved this issue, you should post an answer for your solution rather than update it in your question, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and easier to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive had this issue before, and it often results as in this case, from moving projects around in different folders or some other sort of rearranging of the source.  Then the references get mixed up.  In this case, editing the csproj file it took me a while, but finally seen the extra "." in the pathing.  Once that was fixed, things cleaned up ok.